# When I try to access user's payment details with paypal api its says authorisation failed due to insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, paypal

This is the code which I am doing by following docs and I also have all the permission to access user's data from paypal I did the same process they mention in docs. With the sandbox account it works but not with the real ones.

```
 $.ajax({
                      headers: {
                      "Accept": "application/json",
                      "Accept-Language": "en_US",
                      "Authorization": "Basic "+btoa("${paypalAccId}")
                      },
                      url: "${paypalApi}/v1/oauth2/token",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
                      complete: function(result) {
                     
                      $.ajax({ 
                           type : "GET", 
                           url : "${paypalApi}/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+data.subscriptionID, 
                           beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ result.responseJSON.access_token);
                                                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                                                    },
                           success : function(results) { 
                                                console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: This needs more details, log the full error response -- but typically v1/billing/subscriptions/... is only called by the account receiving the subscription, and if you are calling on behalf of another account that is _receiving_ that subscription you need to send a JWT token or subject header specifying which other account (that you have permission to)

Comment: {name: "NOT_AUTHORIZED", message: "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",…}
debug_id: "2cb8b2bc1b733"
details: [{issue: "PERMISSION_DENIED",…}]
links: [{href: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#NOT_AUTHORIZED",…}]
message: "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions."
name: "NOT_AUTHORIZED"

Comment: This is the response I get from that API

Comment: And I am also using token that I get from my account

Answer (score 0):

`start_time` and `end_time` are required URL parameters for this API call https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_transactions

specify a date before the profile even started if you wish, and specify a date 10 years in the future if you wish, but specify something

Comment: I tried with this but still got the same permission error

Comment: You'll have to share more complete logs then. What is in the string you are encoding for your token, ${paypalAccId} ? What scopes are you getting back in the response?